# Inverse sum representation of sine

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inverse

The other day I was playing with functions of the form

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_0(x-b_0)} + \frac{1}{a_1(x-b_1)} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n(x-b_n)}}
$$

and I found particularly that

$$
\frac{1}{\cdots \frac{1}{x+2\pi} + \frac{-1}{x+\pi} + \frac{1}{x-0} + \frac{-1}{x-\pi} + \frac{1}{x-2\pi} + \cdots}
$$

seems to converge to $\sin x$ rather quickly (at least in comparison to the Maclaurin series representation). In addition, I found quite similar expressions for $\cos$ and $\tan$. How can it be shown that this expression is or is not equal to $\sin x$ (disregarding when $x=n \pi$ for some integer $n$)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Cotangent for more...

Comment: A guess as to how you found this: You noticed that $\frac1x+\frac1{x+1}$ looked similar to the tangent function, but it only had two poles (vertical asymptotes). Playing around got you a function that had the same poles as the tangent function; changing values got you functions with the same poles as the secant ($\sec=\frac1{\cos}$), cosecant ($\csc=\frac1{\sin}$), and cotangent functions. Inverting gives you sine, cosine, tangent, and cotangent.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes that's exactly what happened. How did you know?

Comment: Mostly reverse-engineering from the result. (Also, I saw this sort of thing before.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right. Consider the functions $f(z)=\dfrac 1 z+\sum\limits_{k\geqslant 1}(-1)^k\dfrac{2z}{z^2-k^2}$ and $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}$. You should be able to show that $f(z)$ is meromorphic in $\Bbb C$ with simple poles at the integers, that the same happens with $\sin(\pi z)$, and that $f(z)-g(z)$ is bounded and entire, so that indeed $f(z)=g(z)$ identically since they agree at a point.

Comment: So do you mean $\lim_{n,m} \sum_{k=-m}^n$ converges as $m,n \to \infty$ for those conditionally convergent series?  The conventional way is to combine terms $k$ and $-k$ to get absolutely convergent series.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I haven't yet encountered complex analysis so this is beyond my understanding

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I agree one should combine the symmetric terms.